# Add custom forecasting line in Excel Charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I got the following graph (in purple):

[image]

I want to add the dotted forecasting line.
It's a cell value, but not referenced to the point on the X-Axis (Oktober 13).

I'm a bit lost as to how I could accomplish it. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: From what I understand you are asking; unless the value is tied to the axis for October, all you can do is use line art to place it. Alternately, you could place your forecast values in cells which would allow you to add a second series for a forecast line.

Answer (score 1):

No problem.  Your chart needs two series, one for your actual data (solid line) and one for your projected data (dashed line).  For your second series, just make sure it plots beneath your primary (or you can use #N/A for the non-plotting values).

Here's a sample:

[image: Second Series]